# How can I get the current URL in the SSR of a page

Tags: jss

In my `layout.js` file, I get the current URL of the page with this code:

```
url: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.href : '',
```

On first request of this page from the server, the url is set to ' ' since we have no `window` in the SSR of a page.

How can I get this information in the SSR?

Comment: We tried this to retrieve the canonical url but it failed. The workaround we did is to extend the layoutServiceContext to add the url.

Comment: Would you be willing to post the code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On first load, it is the NodeJS which is compiling the HTML Markup via the SSR. This is why the `window` is null. In order to have the url, I had to extend the `LayoutServiceContext`.

```
public class LayoutSiteContextExtension : IGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor
{
    public void Process(GetLayoutServiceContextArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        if (Context.Site == null)
            return;

        //Canonical URL
        if (!args.ContextData.ContainsKey("canonicalUrl"))
        {
            var targetHostname = Context.Site.TargetHostName;

            var itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Context.Item);

            var canonicalUrl = itemUrl.Equals("/")
                ? $"{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme}://{targetHostname}" 
                : $"{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme}://{targetHostname}{itemUrl}";

            args.ContextData.Add("canonicalUrl", canonicalUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have implemented the above, you need to patch it with a config file as shown below

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="layoutService">
        <pipelines>
          <getLayoutServiceContext>
            <processor type="Your Namespace, Your Assembly Name"
                       patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.Pipelines.GetLayoutServiceContext.SiteContext, Sitecore.LayoutService']"/>
          </getLayoutServiceContext>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's not obvious what to reference to get the IGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor, but I found it by doing "Install-Package sitecore.LayoutService", although you could probably just reference the sitecore.layoutservice dll

Comment: Also on the page you need to use: withSitecoreContext(), and you can then get the value from props.sitecoreContext.canonicalUrl